# Improving animating width performance

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I have a simple layout with a main section and a sidebar. I need to expand/collapse the sidebar horizontally, the sidebar should also push the main section.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: coral;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

aside {
  width: 24px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 200ms ease;
}

aside.open {
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
          pharetra, orci ut faucibus faucibus, risus augue mattis eros, et
          maximus mauris libero quis elit. Curabitur porta ac ante accumsan
          imperdiet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
          pharetra, orci ut faucibus faucibus, risus augue mattis eros, et
          maximus mauris libero quis elit. Curabitur porta ac ante accumsan
          imperdiet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
          pharetra, orci ut faucibus faucibus, risus augue mattis eros, et
          maximus mauris libero quis elit. Curabitur porta ac ante accumsan
          imperdiet.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </main>
    <aside></aside>
    <script>
      const aside = document.querySelector("aside");
      document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
        if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
          aside.classList.add("open");
        }
        if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
          aside.classList.remove("open");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-wind-elo67e?file=/style.css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
          pharetra, orci ut faucibus faucibus, risus augue mattis eros, et
          maximus mauris libero quis elit. Curabitur porta ac ante accumsan
          imperdiet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
          pharetra, orci ut faucibus faucibus, risus augue mattis eros, et
          maximus mauris libero quis elit. Curabitur porta ac ante accumsan
          imperdiet.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris
          pharetra, orci ut faucibus faucibus, risus augue mattis eros, et
          maximus mauris libero quis elit. Curabitur porta ac ante accumsan
          imperdiet.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </main>
    <aside></aside>
    <script>
      const aside = document.querySelector("aside");
      document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
        if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
          aside.classList.add("open");
        }
        if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
          aside.classList.remove("open");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: coral;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

aside {
  width: 24px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 200ms ease;
}

aside.open {
  width: 240px;
}
```

That code just works but it proceeds low performance when there are many components in the main section e.g. List.

As we know we should use CSS Transform over animating width/height cause it provokes style/layout/paint etc.

The question is can I really improve the performance of animation if I'll replace animating width with some transform animation?

I have tried using scale(), but there are 2 problems:

1. using px is preferable
2. the sidebar doesn't push the main section

Thanks

Comment: Is there some way you could add things to main in your question so that the problem can be seen. Making it a runnable snippet See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried transforming main at the same time as you transform aside? As you pointed out, transforms can be smoother. Not sure whether this would have any knock on effect as I don't know what's in main.

Comment: I have added the snippet. Imagine that it is a simple blog with posts section and a filter menu. I'm sure that scale will be ugly for text

Comment: I wasn't suggesting scale, just transform the width.

Comment: The snippet doesnt produce any performance issues for me (Edge/WIndows10) - it does look slightly jerky,  but that's because whole words are being wrapped. What browser/OS is giving you the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using FLIP technique. Framer Motion has implementation of FLIP named Layout Animation.